# Close multiple firefox windows from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a GWT application which has many firefox windows. I need functionality to close all these windows with a single click on a button. I know the window.close() function, but it only closes the current window. 
I wonder if there is a firefox plugin or anything what can help me achieve this functionality.

In Firefox the File menu contains an Exit button what terminates the program, but i can't find a way to call this from javascript.

Comment: I'm glad it's not possible

Comment: if there is a solution, it will likely have to be a hack that will eventually be patched up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close other windows with script that didn't open them. But

```
var newWindow = window.open( url );
newWindow.close();
```

will open new tab with url and then you will be able to close it with `newWindow.close()`;

Answer (score 0):

When a new window is opened with `window.open()`, a reference to the new window is returned.
This means `var window1 = window.open("example.com", "windowName");` will allow you to close the this new window later with `window1.close();`

Windows are often opened this way to address your problem, though if the windowName specified existed already, the existing window would be used to load the page instead, and the variable would refer to the existing window.

EDIT: This explains browser windows and associated window control JavaScript [here](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#Referencing%20Windows)